# PHP preg_match() to validate international phone number by meeting specific criteria

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to validate a given international phone number using php preg_match() function following these rules:
- Only digits allowed, no special chars and white spaces

- phone number must starts always with '00' not +
- phone number length should be not lower than 11 symbols

So far I have this which checks the beginning of the string:

```
preg_match("~^00\d+$~", $_POST['phone'])
```

but if I pass: 00014568978945 it will accept it as correct as it checks to has min '00' but third '0' makes the phone invalid..

How should look like the full preg_match() condition to check for above requirements? Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Try `~^00[1-9]\d{8,}$~D`: starts with two `0`s, then a non-zero digit, and then any 8 or more digits.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, what \d{8,} means?

Comment: *8 or more digits*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

```
 ~^00[1-9]\d{8,}$~D
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z6dCtS/1).

**Details**:

- `^00` - starts with two `0`s, then
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit, and then
- `\d{8,}` - any 8 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Since you are *validating*, I also included `D` *PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY* modifier that forces the `$` anchor to always match the *very* end of the string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, seems to work, I will accept it in 7 mins.